# Proving surjectivity of $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ where $U =ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $U$ is a three dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{R^8}$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R^8},\mathbf{R^5})$ such that $null\ T = U$, prove that $T$ is *surjective*.

**Proof.** From use of the *Fundamental-Theorem-of-Linear-Maps* we see that 
$$\dim range\ T = \dim V-\dim null\ T\tag{1}$$
and since we know that $\dim null\ T = \dim U = 3$ it follows that $\dim range\ T = 5$, moreover we know that $range\ T \leqslant \mathbf{R^5}$ it then follows that $range\ T$ must be *finite-dimensional* consequently we may invoke the existence of the vectors 
$$w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5\in\mathbf{R^5}$$ such that they act as a basis for $range\ T$, evidently the above list of vectors is *linearly-independent* and thus by $\mathbf{(2.39)}$ it follows that the also act as a basis for $W$, from which we may infer that $range\ T = W$ indicating that $T$ is *surjective*.

$\blacksquare$

Note: Here $\mathbf{2.39}$ is the result that a linearly independent list in finite-dimensional vector space $V$ having a length equal to $\dim V$ is a basis for $V$

Comment: Why is $\dim U=3$? Is there a hypothesis missing from the theorem?

Comment: Apologies i forgot to mention that in the statement of the theorem